# SQLITE DATABASE for multiple access

Tags: android, sqlite

I would like to ask if any of you out there uses android studio and sqlite for apps that require multiple users to access the database? I have been looking for source codes and examples online, but haven't seen any. I understand that other database might be better but I only have enough time to use sqlite as I am alr using it now. Could anyone help me with example source codes?

Comment: You can use List<>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
viewComment.setText(name+comment);
```

replace with below code

```
viewComment.append("\n"+name+comment);
```

Update -

1. limit number comments - use counter , after certain number of hits stop appending to text view.
2. U can make scrollable too.

for above both please check your requirements or UI/UX teams.

Comment: is there a way to set the limit of the number of inputs(button clicked), i do not want the comments to fill up the whole page

Comment: or can i use scrollable view so it will stay inside?

Comment: please accept and upvote ans if ans solves your problems

Answer (score 0):

You will have to work with [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) here. Add a different layout resource file in your layout folder and bind it to the RecyclerView and all your comments must be stored somewhere, like in a database. You will then achieve your desired structure.